# How do I make TTS stop speaking IMMEDIATELY?

Tags: c++, winapi, text-to-speech, sapi

I am using ISpVoice to speak an input string. Now, even though I use `SPF_ASYNC` and `SPF_PURGEBEFORESPEAK` tags in the `Speak` method, the tts doesn't stop whenever `Pause` is called instead it continues until the tts finishes a word.

Here's how I do it:

```
void speakSentence()
{
    pVoice->Pause();
    pVoice->Speak(L"This is a sentence.", SPF_ASYNC | SPF_PURGEBEFORESPEAK, NULL);
    pVoice->Resume();
}
```

Whenever I try to call this function at the middle of the word "sentence", the tts doesn't pause and instead continues to say the word until the end.

From microsoft documentation:

> ISpVoice::Pause pauses the voice at the nearest alert boundary and closes the output device, allowing access to pending speak requests from other voices.

I tried changing the alert boundary by:

```
pVoice->SetAlertBoundary(SPEI_PHONEME);
```

and it doesn't work.

There is NVDA Screen Reader that solved this problem but I don't know how they did it.

Is there anyway to solve my problem?

EDIT: 
Here's my full code. I am creating a small screen reader program that uses both UIAutomation and MSAA.
The program may somewhat unstable when comparing UI objects but most times it works.

screeenreader.h:

```
#ifndef _SCREENREADER_H_
#define _SCREENREADER_H_

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <windows.h>

#include <memory>

#include "speechsynthesis.h"
#include "uiautomator.h"

class ScreenReader
{
public:
    explicit ScreenReader(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR pScmdline, int iCmdShow);
    virtual ~ScreenReader();

    LRESULT CALLBACK MessageHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    int Exec();
private:
    void InitializeWindows();
    void InitRawInputDevices();
    bool IsMouseMove();
private:
    LPCWSTR m_applicationName;
    HINSTANCE m_hInstance;
    HINSTANCE m_hPrevInstance;
    PSTR m_pScmdline;
    int m_iCmdShow;

    HWND m_hWnd;

    SpeechSynthesis *m_pSpeech;
    UIAutomator *m_pAutomator;

    RAWINPUTDEVICE rid[2];

    LONG m_prevMouseX;
    LONG m_prevMouseY;

    BSTR currItem;
};

static ScreenReader *application;

static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

#endif
```

screenreader.cpp: In this part I called ISpVoice at the messageloop section. At `ScreenReader::MessageHandler()` function at `IsMouseMove` condition.

```
#include "screenreader.h"



ScreenReader::ScreenReader(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR pScmdline, int iCmdShow)
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    m_pSpeech = new SpeechSynthesis;
    m_pAutomator = new UIAutomator;

    // Get current Cursor position.
    POINT pt;
    GetCursorPos(&pt);
    m_prevMouseX = pt.x;
    m_prevMouseY = pt.y;

    // Notify user the program is loading.
    m_pSpeech->Speak(L"Loading Rescan. Please wait.", SPF_DEFAULT, NULL);
    m_hInstance = hInstance;
    m_hPrevInstance = hPrevInstance;
    m_pScmdline = pScmdline;
    m_iCmdShow = iCmdShow;

    application = this;
    InitializeWindows();
    InitRawInputDevices();
}


ScreenReader::~ScreenReader()
{
    if (m_pSpeech != nullptr)
    {
        delete m_pSpeech;
        m_pSpeech = nullptr;
    }
    if (m_pAutomator != nullptr)
    {
        delete m_pAutomator;
        m_pAutomator = nullptr;
    }
    if (currItem != NULL)
    {
        SysFreeString(currItem);
        currItem = NULL;
    }
    CoUninitialize();
}

LRESULT CALLBACK ScreenReader::MessageHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INPUT:
    {
        UINT dwSize;
        GetRawInputData(
            (HRAWINPUT)lParam,
            RID_INPUT,
            NULL,
            &dwSize,
            sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)
        );
        std::unique_ptr<BYTE[]> lpb(new BYTE[dwSize]);
        if (!lpb)
            return 0;
        if (GetRawInputData(
            (HRAWINPUT)lParam,
            RID_INPUT,
            lpb.get(),
            &dwSize,
            sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)
        ) != dwSize)
            OutputDebugString(L"GetRawInputData does not return correct size!\n");

        RAWINPUT *raw = (RAWINPUT*)lpb.get();
        if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD)
        {
            UINT mess = raw->data.keyboard.Message;
            UINT vKey = raw->data.keyboard.VKey;
            if (mess == WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
            }
        }
        else if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE)
        {
            if (IsMouseMove())
            {
                BSTR item;
                HRESULT hr = m_pAutomator->GetUIAutomationItemNameAtMousePoint(&item);
                if (item == NULL)
                    return 0;
                if (currItem == NULL)
                    currItem = SysAllocString(item);
                if (wcscmp(currItem, item) != 0)
                {
                    m_pSpeech->Stop();
                    m_pSpeech->Speak(item);
                    if (currItem != NULL)
                        SysFreeString(currItem);
                    currItem = SysAllocString(item);
                }
                SysFreeString(item);
            }
        }
    }
        return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

int ScreenReader::Exec()
{
    MSG msg;

    ShowWindow(m_hWnd, m_iCmdShow);

    // Tell the user that the program is ready.
    m_pSpeech->Speak(L"Rescan ready.", SPF_PURGEBEFORESPEAK);

    // The message loop
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

void ScreenReader::InitializeWindows()
{
    // Create Window class.
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    m_applicationName = L"Rescan Screen Reader";

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = m_hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = m_applicationName;
    wc.hIconSm = wc.hIcon;

    // Register the window class.
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        m_applicationName,
        L"Rescan Screen Reader",
        WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU,
        (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - 500) / 2,
        (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - 300) / 2,
        500,
        300,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        m_hInstance,
        NULL
    );
}

void ScreenReader::InitRawInputDevices()
{
    // Initialize Keyboard
    rid[0].usUsagePage = 0x01;
    rid[0].usUsage = 0x06;
    rid[0].dwFlags = RIDEV_INPUTSINK;
    rid[0].hwndTarget = m_hWnd;
    // Initialize Mouse
    rid[1].usUsagePage = 0x01;
    rid[1].usUsage = 0x02;
    rid[1].dwFlags = RIDEV_INPUTSINK;
    rid[1].hwndTarget = m_hWnd;

    // Register RIDs
    RegisterRawInputDevices(rid, 2, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE));
}

bool ScreenReader::IsMouseMove()
{
    POINT pt;
    GetCursorPos(&pt);
    bool result = !(m_prevMouseX == pt.x && m_prevMouseY == pt.y);
    m_prevMouseX = pt.x;
    m_prevMouseY = pt.y;
    return result;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_QUIT:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    default:
        return application->MessageHandler(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

I wrapped ISpVoice into the SpeechSynthesis class.

speechsynthesis.h:

```
#ifndef _SPEECHSYNTHESIS_H_
#define _SPEECHSYNTHESIS_H_

#pragma warning(disable :  4996)

#define SPCAT_VOICES_ONECORE L"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Speech_OneCore\\Voices"

#include <sapi.h>
#include <sphelper.h>
#include <atlbase.h>

class SpeechSynthesis
{
public:
    SpeechSynthesis();
    ~SpeechSynthesis();

    HRESULT Speak(LPCWSTR pwcs, DWORD dwFlags = SPF_PURGEBEFORESPEAK | SPF_ASYNC | SPF_IS_NOT_XML, ULONG *pulStreamNumber = NULL);
    HRESULT Resume();
    HRESULT Pause();
    HRESULT Stop();

    ISpVoice* getVoice();

private:
    CComPtr<ISpObjectToken> cpVoiceToken;
    CComPtr<IEnumSpObjectTokens> cpEnum;
    ISpVoice* pVoice;
    ULONG count;
};

#endif
```

speechsynthesis.cpp:

```
#include "speechsynthesis.h"



SpeechSynthesis::SpeechSynthesis()
{
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_ISpVoice, (void **)&pVoice);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = SpEnumTokens(SPCAT_VOICES_ONECORE, NULL, NULL, &cpEnum);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = cpEnum->GetCount(&count);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        cpEnum->Item(1, &cpVoiceToken);
        pVoice->SetPriority(SPVPRIORITY::SPVPRI_ALERT);
        pVoice->SetAlertBoundary(SPEI_PHONEME);
        pVoice->SetOutput(NULL, TRUE);
        pVoice->SetVoice(cpVoiceToken);
    }
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "A fatal error has occured", "Error Message", MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE);
    }
}


SpeechSynthesis::~SpeechSynthesis()
{
    pVoice->Release();
}

HRESULT SpeechSynthesis::Speak(LPCWSTR pwcs, DWORD dwFlags, ULONG *pulStreamNumber)
{
    return pVoice->Speak(pwcs, dwFlags, pulStreamNumber);
}

HRESULT SpeechSynthesis::Resume()
{
    return pVoice->Resume();
}

HRESULT SpeechSynthesis::Pause()
{
    return pVoice->Pause();
}

HRESULT SpeechSynthesis::Stop()
{
    return Speak(NULL);
}

ISpVoice * SpeechSynthesis::getVoice()
{
    return pVoice;
}
```

uiautomator.h

```
#ifndef _UIAUTOMATOR_H_
#define _UIAUTOMATOR_H_

#include <windows.h>
#include <oleacc.h>
#include <uiautomation.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "oleacc.lib")

class UIAutomator
{
public:
    UIAutomator();
    ~UIAutomator();

    HRESULT GetItemNameAtMousePoint(BSTR *pStr);
    HRESULT GetUIAutomationItemNameAtMousePoint(BSTR *pStr);
private:
    HRESULT InitUIAutomation();

private:
    IUIAutomation *m_automation;
};

#endif
```

uiautomator.cpp

```
#include "uiautomator.h"



UIAutomator::UIAutomator()
{
    SetProcessDPIAware();
    HRESULT hr = InitUIAutomation();
}


UIAutomator::~UIAutomator()
{
}

HRESULT UIAutomator::GetItemNameAtMousePoint(BSTR * pStr)
{
    POINT pt;
    GetPhysicalCursorPos(&pt);
    VARIANT varItem;
    IAccessible *pAcc;
    HRESULT hr = AccessibleObjectFromPoint(pt, &pAcc, &varItem);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pAcc->get_accName(varItem, pStr);
        VariantClear(&varItem);
        pAcc->Release();
    }
    return hr;
}

HRESULT UIAutomator::GetUIAutomationItemNameAtMousePoint(BSTR * pStr)
{
    CONTROLTYPEID id;
    POINT pt;
    IUIAutomationElement *elem;
    VARIANT val;
    GetCursorPos(&pt);
    HRESULT hr = m_automation->ElementFromPoint(pt, &elem);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = elem->get_CurrentControlType(&id);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            if (id == UIA_PaneControlTypeId)
                GetItemNameAtMousePoint(pStr);
            else if (id == UIA_EditControlTypeId)
            {
                hr = elem->GetCurrentPropertyValue(UIA_ValueValuePropertyId, &val);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    *pStr = SysAllocString(val.bstrVal);
                    VariantClear(&val);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                hr = elem->get_CurrentName(pStr);
            }
        }
        elem->Release();
    }
    return hr;
}

HRESULT UIAutomator::InitUIAutomation()
{
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(CUIAutomation), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        __uuidof(IUIAutomation), (void**)&m_automation);
    return hr;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "vld.h"
#include "screenreader.h"
#include <memory>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR pScmdline, int iCmdShow)
{
    std::unique_ptr<ScreenReader> app(new ScreenReader(hInstance, hPrevInstance, pScmdline, iCmdShow));
    return app->Exec();
}
```

[If you don't have time to compile here's the program.](https://github.com/Subalzero/Rescan---Screen-Reader-for-The-Blind-v0.1alpha/blob/master/RescanScreenReaderWin.exe)

If you launch it and hover the mouse on the program window there is a lag when highlighting minimize and close button. Also sometimes the tts doesn't stop immediately when you hover at another object.

Compare this one to NVDA Screen Reader. You will notice the big difference.

Comment: `voice->Speak( nullptr, SPF_ASYNC | SPF_IS_NOT_XML | SPF_PURGEBEFORESPEAK, nullptr );` stops TTS almost imediatelly. For using `Pause` and `Resume` I would expect you to use two different `ISpVoice` or use different priorities.

Comment: @DanielSęk I want to know how screen readers does this where the tts stops immediately then start speaking a new sentence with very little start delay. So far I was not able to do it using the code you suggested. Do you have any sources on how they do it?

Comment: I'm using TTS in my program [Easy Rider](http://danielsek.pl/easyrider.html)  (unfortunatelly only in Polish language) and I don't have any problems. I can stop or restart sentence almost imediatelly. To start speaking I use `hr = m_voice->Speak( text, SPF_ASYNC | SPF_IS_NOT_XML | SPF_PURGEBEFORESPEAK, nullptr );` and to stop `voice->Speak( nullptr, SPF_ASYNC | SPF_IS_NOT_XML | SPF_PURGEBEFORESPEAK, nullptr );`

Comment: @AlzerCasiño How do you control `pause` at at the middle of the word "sentence"?

Comment: @Alzer Casiño Can you show a simple complete code that can reproduce your issue?

Comment: @DanielSęk I already updated my question.

Comment: Are you sure that your problem is in speech engine? Maybe create some two buttons which will call `SpeechSynthesis::Speak` and `SpeechSynthesis::Stop` and verify that problem really lies in `SpeechSynthesis` class. Something like [TTS start/stop test](https://youtu.be/L1Hj1yUTTeM) The only bigger difference is that my code uses `SPCAT_VOICES` not `SPCAT_VOICES_ONECORE`.

Comment: I defined `SPCAT_VOICES_ONECORE` in order for the engine to use Microsoft OneCore voices. Maybe my last choice would be is to reverse engineer NVDA Screen Reader on how they process their speech. Or maybe I have to access the audiostream and remove the data.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me with or without setting `SetAlertBoundary(SPEI_PHONEME)`.

The following is my test code, you can have a try.

```
HRESULT hr = ::CoInitialize(nullptr);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
std::wstring text;

text = L"This is a sentence.";

CComPtr<ISpVoice> cpVoice;
// Create a SAPI voice
hr = cpVoice.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice);
//cpVoice->SetAlertBoundary(SPEI_PHONEME);
// set the output to the default audio device
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = cpVoice->SetOutput(NULL, TRUE);
}
// Speak the text
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = cpVoice->Speak(text.c_str(), SPF_ASYNC | SPF_PURGEBEFORESPEAK, NULL);
}

text = L"The third type, a logarithm of the unsigned fold change, is undoubtedly the most tractable.";

Sleep(600);

hr = cpVoice->Pause();      
hr = cpVoice->Resume();
hr = cpVoice->Speak(text.c_str(), SPF_ASYNC | SPF_PURGEBEFORESPEAK, NULL);

Sleep(10000);

::CoUninitialize();
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

Comment: Is there any difference when you remove `Pause` and `Remove` calls?

Comment: ^^ Should be `Resume`

Comment: I would like to see more code from @AlzerCasiño also, because I'm not sure what he really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it!

```
CComPtr<ISpAudio> audio;
CSpStreamFormat format;
format.AssignFormat(SPSF_11kHz8BitMono);
```

Initialize audio

```
SpCreateDefaultObjectFromCategoryId(SPCAT_AUDIOOUT, &audio);
```

Then, set its format and set it as output to pVoice.

```
audio->SetFormat(format.FormatId(), format.WaveFormatExPtr());
pVoice->SetOutput(audio, FALSE);
```

Now I have access to the audio stream!

Now to Immediately stop the audio, call:

```
audio->SetState(SPAS_STOP, 0);
```

Then speak again using:

```
audio->SetState(SPAS_RUN, 0);
pVoice->Speak(L"This is a sentence", SPF_ASYNC | SPF_PURGEBEFORESPEAK, NULL);
```